# how to call a springboot service endpoint from apache kafka and pass all the messages from a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to kafka technology and I have a requirement of fetch all the realtime data from a DB and pass it to a springboot microservice for its processing. in my analysis found that apache kafka with kafka source connect can pull all real time data from the DB to kafka Topics.
Can someone tell is there any way to pick this data form kafka topics and share to microservice by trigger a restcall from the kafka service ?
The idea is whenever a new entry added to the database table kafka can pull that data via kafka connect and somehow kafka should call the microservice and share this new entry. is it possible with kafka ?

Database --> kafka connect --> kafka (Topic) ---> *some service that call microservice*  ---> microservice

Comment: you implement a stream handler in your microservice, it gets called with every event coming from the topic, alternatively you can use the pub/sub API pattern. Pushing messages to a rest endpoint may be useful in terms of integration scenarios, but you seem to be a direct consumer. So use kafka APIs directly.

Comment: @thst  - if I use pub/sub API pattern, the pub (in my case it is DB) and sub (microservice) should call the kafka service to push/pull the data to topic. which is not possible in this scenario. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You subscribe to the topic, kafka connect fills the topic. Kafka-connect publishes events into the topic. It is conceptually roughly like messaging (JMS), but it is advanced and works very different in detail. I suggest, you work through a tutorial or grab a kafka book to understand the fundamentals of your application architecture better.

Comment: Add-on: Look at the spring-boot kafka integration with the `@KafkaListener` annotation

Answer (score 0):

> form kafka topics and share to microservice

Kafka doesn't push. You would add a consumer in your service to pull from Kafka, perhaps using `spring-kafka` or `spring-cloud-streams`

Alternatively, Kafka Connect Sink could be used with an HTTP POST connector, but then you'd need to somehow deal with not committing offsets for messages that have failed requests.